# Other examples of Enclave created for protection of a Mixed Race

Tags: 20th-century, india, race

[McCluskieganj](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McCluskieganj)/[McCluskiegunj](http://www.livemint.com/Leisure/FJ2fiR6BjwGaKa7U2gsQyK/McCluskieganj-Jharkhand--Remains-of-a-promised-land.html) was a town created out of several villages to secure a place for **Anglo-Indians**.

Disambiguation:
By **Anglo-Indians** I mean it in the way it has been used since the **Indian census of 1911**, i.e a domiciled community of **mixed descent**, who were formerly known as Eurasian, country-born or half-caste, and not as in the nineteenth and early twentieth centuries, when it referred to the British in India.

**Ernest Timothy McCluskie**, a land and house agent from Calcutta, founded the **Colonization Society of India Ltd** in 1933 in Calcutta with the idea of establishing an Anglo-Indian refuge, where their racial insecurities could be put to rest. This is thus several years before India's independence, under British rule, but within the context of imminent independence, when the British would leave.

It has been described as:

> [It] is the only homeland that Anglo-Indians worldwide can claim as
>   their very own – the leftover of a dream for independence. --
>   Vaihayasi Daniel in Sunday Mid-Day in 1992.

My question is: are there any other examples of enclaves **`created`** solely for protecting people of mixed descent? By `created` I mean something that did not grow due to influx or settlement, that is, without a laid out charter.

Comment: Most of such enclaves would probably have been set up in South Africa. That was the "ultimate" social experiment in mixed race relations.

Comment: Sounds good/interesting @TomAu.

Comment: Care to explain the downvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whitefield, Bangalore, was older but smaller than McCluskieganj. Legend has it Winstorn Churchill courted the daughter of a hotel keeper there. Vide https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitefield,_Bangalore

Comment: Interesting. Especially since I live right next door. I'm accepting the answer since no other answer has been provided in a long while.